# Add a link in one of column while binding data to div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I bring data thorugh `json` and bind it in a `div`. Now what I want is, the column is dynamically generated with its data. So there is one column in response whose name is `APPLICATIONNAME` for which there will be `a` tag. The link is created with below code.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index/" + SMenu.id, "Application")" class="menuCall">
```

and my response and its data binding code is below

```
success: function (data) {
            var html = '';

            if (data == "") {
                $("#dvTable").html('No Data Found');
            }

            else {
                var rData = JSON.parse(data);

                if (rData.length !== 0) {

                    html += '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-blue">';

                    for (var key in rData) {
                        var row = rData[key];
                        if (key == 0) {
                            html += '<tr>';
                            for (var key2 in row) {
                                html += '<th>';
                                html += key2;
                                html += '</th>';
                            }
                            html += '</tr>';
                        }
                        html += '<tr>';
                        for (var key2 in row) {
                            html += '<td>';
                            html += row[key2];
                            html += '</td>';
                        }
                        html += '</tr>';
                    }
                    html += '</table></div>';
                }
                else {
                    html += "No Data Found";
                }

                $("#dvTable").html(html);
            }
        }
```

So how should I link and make it clickable.

**JSON Code**

`APP_MST_ID` is SMenu.id which will be used for URL

**UPDATE**

Returning json code from controller.

```
public ActionResult GetSearchData(string ddlSelectedVal, string ddlselectParamType, string ddlselectOperator, string txtSearchCntrl)
    {
        string JSONresult = string.Empty;
        SearchComponentBLL srchData = new SearchComponentBLL();
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DS = srchData.GET_FILTER_DATA(ddlSelectedVal, ddlselectParamType, ddlselectOperator, txtSearchCntrl);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        if (DS != null && DS.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DT = DS.Tables[0];
            if (DT != null && DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DT);
            }
        }
        return Json(JSONresult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Not really clear how you want to use that data. Is `APPLICATIONNAME` supposed to be the text for the link, and `URL` the value for the `href` attribute, or are you wanting `href="/Application/Index/xxx` where `xxx` is the value of `APP_MST_ID`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: No `APPLICATIONNAME` is my column name, the values will be `NE ISP Inventory Reporting Application` which will be the text for the link. the `ID ` will be `APP_MST_ID` for forming the link

Comment: Yes, That is what I mean :) So you want to generate `<a href="/Application/Index/267.0">NE ISP Inventory Reporting Application</a>` for the first one (which by the way wont work because of the `.` in the url)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: a bit of correction in the url u gave `<a href="Index/" + SMenu.id, "Application"`>NE ISP Inventory Reporting Application</a>` and `SMenu.id` will be `APP_MST_ID`. also can we remove `.` while binding to url ?

Comment: `href="Index/" + SMenu.id, "Application"` makes no sense (what would you expect that to hit?) I assume you confusing the `Url.Action()` method with the actual html it generates. And in any case, that is not the way to use `Url.Action()` - it would be `@Url.Action("Index", "Application", new { id = SMenu.id })`

Comment: And if you do not want the `.` in the url, then it should not be in your data your sending in the first place. And why do you have `var rData = JSON.parse(data);` - that can only mean your serializing the data on the server twice in order to undo it.

Comment: oh, maybe i m not much aware about mvc, the url u gave might be correct..ok.will remove `.` while sending it from the database. so after that can we achieve the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165401/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-vvvv).

Comment: How about just an event listener on jQuery and not necessarily a link?

Answer (score 1):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
success: function (data) {
            var html = '';

            if (data == "") {
                $("#dvTable").html('No Data Found');
            }

            else {
                 var rData = JSON.parse(data);
                 var html = '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-blue">';
                 for (var key in rData) {
                    var row = rData[key];
                    if (key == 0) {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        for (var key2 in row) {
                            html += '<th>';
                            html += key2;
                            html += '</th>';
                        }
                        html += '</tr>';
                    }
                 }

                $.each(rData,function(index,value){
                        html+="<tr><td>"+value['APP_MST_ID']+"</td><td><a href='/Application/Index/"+value['APP_MST_ID']+"' class='menuCall'>"+value['APPLICATIONNAME']+"</a></td><td>"+value['URL']+"</td><td>"+value['PROJECTNO']+"</td><td>"+value['VSSFOLDERLOC']+"</td><td>"+value['SPOCUSER']+"</td><td>"+value['REQUESTEDBY']+"</td><td>"+value['DELIVERYMANAGER']+"</td></tr>";                 
                });

               html += '</table></div>';
               $("#dvTable").append(html);
            }
        }
```

Comment: sure with the help of this code you can do the same operations inside your success call.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I think that will be useful to you.

Comment: href is not generated properly. coming like this `<a href="/Application/Index/" 1="">LCO Mapping Application</a>` something like this is expected `<a href="@Url.Action("Index/" + SMenu.id, "Application")" class="menuCall">`

Comment: one more thing, your column name is hardcoded.`<th>APPLICATIONNAME</th>`... whiich is not proper if I take second condition

Comment: it is not working for second condition. check the link for `json` data:- https://jsfiddle.net/skLuLvt5/

Comment: **please note** the column name should be dynamic that is why it is not working for second condition.

Comment: are you their mate ?

Comment: hi abhilash, can u help me bro ??

Answer (score 1):

First, your unnecessarily serializing your data twice in the controller method (which means you then need `JSON.parse()` to convert it back again), and all you need is in the method is

```
return Json(DT, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In the script, assign the 'base url' to a variable so that you can use that for constructing the url containing the route value based on `APP_MST_ID`. Note the following code uses jQuery objects for generating the html, rather than your current html string (which can be difficult to debug).

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Application")';
$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            var html = $('<div></div>').addClass('table-responsive');
            var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table table-blue');
            html.append(table);
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                // Create table row
                var row = $('<tr></tr>');
                // Create table link
                var link = $('<a></a>').text(item.APPLICATIONNAME)
                    .attr('href', baseUrl + '/' + item.APP_MST_ID).addClass('menuCall'); 
                // Create table cell
                var cell = $('<td></td>');
                cell.append(link);
                row.append(cell);
                // .... more table columns as required
                table.append(row); 
            });
        $("#dvTable").html(html);
        }
    }
});
```

There is however an issue with the value of `APP_MST_ID` because it contains a `.` (dot) and you will have [this problem](Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS) if its a route value. The alternative of the `.` is necessary if you add it as a query string, i.e.

```
var link = $('<a></a>').text(item.APPLICATIONNAME)
    .attr('href', baseUrl + '?id=' + item.APP_MST_ID).addClass('menuCall');
```

Another option for generating the html is to create a hidden template which can be cloned and updated, for example

```
<table id="template" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <a href="" class="menuCall"></a>
        </td>
        // .... other columns as required
    <tr>
<table>
```

and then in your script

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Application")';
var template = $('#template');
....

$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    var clone = template.clone.html(); // returns the tr
    table.append(clone);
    var cells = clone.find('td');
    cells.eq(0).text(item.APP_MST_ID); // update first column
    cells.eq(1).find('a').text(item.APPLICATIONNAME).attr('href', baseUrl + '?id=' + item.APP_MST_ID);
    .... // update other columns as required
});
```